# AWS DMS CDC failing to replicate text column from MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

We are using AWS DMS to replicate data from MySQL to Aurora MySQL with ongoing replication. We setup task validation to ensure source to target replication was successful. One of the tables has a text column which fails validation for ongoing replication. The tasks replicates the column properly during full load but during ongoing replication, the target column is always empty string.

The schemas for the source and target are identical.

Below are the task settings for the replication task.

```
{
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "TargetSchema": "mydb",
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "FullLobMode": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 64,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": false,
        "LobMaxSize": 0,
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DO_NOTHING",
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CommitRate": 10000
    },
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-test-dms-replication-instance",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task"
    },
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 50,
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 50,
        "RecoverableErrorCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
    },
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "StatementCacheSize": 50
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null
}
```

I have been having issue finding anything on this. Does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Have you set the rds.logical_replication flag to 1?